# How to load a PKCS#12 file in OpenSSL programmatically?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, pkcs#12

In an SSL Server Application based on OpenSSL, how can we load a PKCS#12 file programmatically?

Also, can I load a PKCS#12 file having Certificate, Key & CAs in the same file in OpenSSL?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes you can load a PKCS#12 file containing certificate, key and CAs in the same file with OpenSSL.

- Use `d2i_PKCS12_fp()` or `d2i_PKCS12_bio()` to load the PKCS#12 file.
- Optionally use `PKCS12_verify_mac()` to verify the password.
- Use `PKCS12_parse()` which decrypts and extracts key, certificate and CA chain for you.

From [openssl-1.0.0d/demos/pkcs12/pkread.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/demos/pkcs12/pkread.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/pkcs12.h>

/* Simple PKCS#12 file reader */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey;
    X509 *cert;
    STACK_OF(X509) *ca = NULL;
    PKCS12 *p12;
    int i;
    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: pkread p12file password opfile\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    if (!(fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    p12 = d2i_PKCS12_fp(fp, NULL);
    fclose (fp);
    if (!p12) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading PKCS#12 file\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit (1);
    }
    if (!PKCS12_parse(p12, argv[2], &pkey, &cert, &ca)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing PKCS#12 file\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit (1);
    }
    PKCS12_free(p12);
    if (!(fp = fopen(argv[3], "w"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pkey) {
        fprintf(fp, "***Private Key***\n");
        PEM_write_PrivateKey(fp, pkey, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    }
    if (cert) {
        fprintf(fp, "***User Certificate***\n");
        PEM_write_X509_AUX(fp, cert);
    }
    if (ca && sk_X509_num(ca)) {
        fprintf(fp, "***Other Certificates***\n");
        for (i = 0; i < sk_X509_num(ca); i++) 
            PEM_write_X509_AUX(fp, sk_X509_value(ca, i));
    }

    sk_X509_pop_free(ca, X509_free);
    X509_free(cert);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Mathias  The above code u gave is used to read an DER encode P12 certificate . is there any API to read PEM encoded P12 certificate

Comment: @Balamurugan: I've never seen a PEM-encoded PKCS#12 file or software that supported it.

Comment: I wonder if you can expand this answer so it parses the PKCS12 structure without leaking memory (ie, so it is suitable for use in a long-running program).  In particular, PKCS12_parse seems to leak about 4kB.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: I added the additional cleanups of ca, cert and pkey. I still have a leak with OpenSSL 0.9.8 but not with 1.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

Be warned that the code writes the certs out as trusted certificates (encrypted).
If you want unencrypted certificates, change the calls to PEM_write_X509_AUX() to PEM_write_X509().

Comment: That text should really be in the comments.

Comment: This was my issue was the tags were BEGIN TRUSTED CERTIFICATE instead of Just BEGIN CERTIFICATE

Answer (score 0):

Try `man SSL`, which gives you a list of OpenSSL functions. Something like `SSL_load_client_CA_file` might suit your needs; it depends if the certificate is in a file on disk or already in memory. There are lots of helper functions, one of them will do the trick. Also check out `man PEM` for PEM handling routines.

*Edit:* Hm, maybe a combination of `d2i_PKCS12_fp` and `PKCS12_parse` (both available from `<openssl/pkcs12.h>`) lets you read a certificate from file and parse it.