# Get key and certificate from *.pfx file using openssl and C

Tags: c, openssl, certificate, key

I have this code:

```
int importKey(){

FILE *fp=NULL;
RSA *pkey=NULL;
R_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY prk; //special structure

fp = fopen("sslcert/key.pem", "r");

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp, &pkey, NULL, NULL);

if (!pkey)
{
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    d2i_RSAPrivateKey_fp(fp, &pkey);
}

prk.bits=BN_num_bits(pkey->n);
return pkey; //check if pkey==0 or something else
}
```

This works just fine when I give `.pem` file to fp what I created from command line using `openssl -pkcs12 -in file.pfx -out key.pem`. But what I need is to use that pfx file in `fp = fopen()` and somehow "extract" private key inside code and save it into that RSA *pkey and also extract certificate from the same pfx file and save it into X509 *px509 variable. Any help with that?

Meaning I need in fact some openssl functions to do the some routine as that command line command

Comment: PEM is actualy a base64 encoding with some header. U can read the pfx file and do a base64 encode(Available in net), then append headers before calling the function. A tag -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- will be present before PEM data and a -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- will be present after the base64 data.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371775/how-to-load-a-pkcs12-file-in-openssl-programmatically

Comment: No, its not duplicate, but I managed to solve my problem thanks to this post. Problem was that in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371775/how-to-load-a-pkcs12-file-in-openssl-programmatically) key was saved into EVP_PKEY variable and I needed to have key in RSA variable. But then I found openssl conversion function:
`pkey = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(evp_key);`
and it's working like charm now. Thanks for pointing me right direction ;)