# Verify private key pass phrase after extracting key from PKCS#12 file

Tags: c, openssl, pkcs#12

I'm trying to read the PKCS#12 file and extract private key programmatically in C. I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371775/how-to-load-a-pkcs12-file-in-openssl-programmatically) solution, but this program automatically decrypts my private key and checks only the PKCS#12 file password. Is there any way to also verify the private key passphrase?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to do it completely because the machinery lack a MAC. That is, its trial and error - if you don't get an error when you load the key, then the passphrase was probably OK. If there was a MAC, then you woud no for sure with an acceptable error rate.