# https client get with cpp-netlib using a client certificate and password

Tags: ssl, boost, https, client-certificates, cpp-netlib

I am trying to use cppnetlib, or even the boost asio libraries to connect to do a simple url get and pull the resulting page down.

I have gotten it to work with http, and even https usign cppnetlib but I need to supply a client certitifcate that takes a password.. Unforntuntley I am required to use the older v0.10 cppnetlib.

Is this possible to do. I think the answer is to create my own _io_service and custome configure it for the https request with cert and password and then supply that to the boost::network::http:client constructor. The below works in http, and will work for https without a cert requirement.

```
std::string url = "http://www.boost.org";
std::string certFile = "C:\\cert\\mycert.p12";
std::string password = "MyPassWord";
try {
        http::client client;
        http::client::request request(url);
        http::client::response response = client->get(request);

        std::string resultText = static_cast<std::string>(body(response));
        std::cout << resultText << std::endl;
        delete client;
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Caught something connecting " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: I would also except using asio directly for a https get that uses a p12 file and password as a client certificate

Comment: It turns out it cannot be done with cppnetlib  v0.10, I would accept a solution using a standard PEM file using asio from boost 1.49

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v0.10 cppnetlib does not directly support client certifications. Since your using cppnetleb you can use boost asio with boost 1.49

Here is an example code that does most of the asio work
https://github.com/alexandruc/SimpleHttpsClient/blob/master/https_client.cpp

That code is very similar to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp

I am putting both in case the links break. That handles the https connection to do client certification you need to add the following lines to the main function before creating the client:

```
        std::string tempString = "test.pem"; //this is a pem file that contains a private key and a certificate. 

        boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23_client);
        ctx.set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
                                    | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
                                    | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3);
        ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

        ctx.use_certificate_file(tempFileStr.c_str(), boost::asio::ssl::context_base::pem);
        ctx.use_private_key_file(tempFileStr.c_str(), boost::asio::ssl::context_base::pem);
```

However in this example you do not have a PEM file but a p12 file, (pkcs12 format).
openssl can be used to decrypt and create the deisred pem file. I adapted the code below from [How to load a PKCS#12 file in OpenSSL programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371775/how-to-load-a-pkcs12-file-in-openssl-programmatically) Unfortuntely this version of boost does not support certificates in memory so it has to be written, dycrypted to a file. I put this in the temp dir, and it should probably get deleted at the end.

```
std::string _certFile = "C:\\cert\\mycert.p12";
std::string password = "_certPassword";
boost::filesystem::path tempFile = boost::filesystem::temp_directory_path() / "temp.pem";
std::string tempFileStr = tempFile.generic_string();
std::cout<<"Using temp file " << tempFileStr<<std::endl;
try
    {

        //read in the pksc12 file, decode it and write a PEM file
        FILE *fp;
        EVP_PKEY *pkey;
        X509 *cert;
        STACK_OF(X509) *ca = NULL;
        PKCS12 *p12;
        int i;

        OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();
        if (!(fp = fopen(_certFile.c_str(), "rb"))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s\n", _certFile);
            return false;       
        }
        p12 = d2i_PKCS12_fp(fp, NULL);
        fclose (fp);
        if (!p12) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading PKCS#12 file\n");
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            return false; 
        }
        if (!PKCS12_parse(p12, _certpPassword.c_str(), &pkey, &cert, &ca)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing PKCS#12 file\n");
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            return false; 

        }
        PKCS12_free(p12);
        if (!(fp = fopen(tempFileStr.c_str(), "w"))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s\n", tempFileStr.c_str());
            return false; 
        }

        if (pkey) {
            fprintf(fp, "***Private Key***\n");
            PEM_write_PrivateKey(fp, pkey, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
        }
        if (cert) {
            fprintf(fp, "***User Certificate***\n");
            PEM_write_X509(fp, cert);
        }
        if (ca && sk_X509_num(ca)) {
            fprintf(fp, "***Other Certificates***\n");

            for (i = 0; i < sk_X509_num(ca); i++) 
            {
                PEM_write_X509(fp, sk_X509_value(ca, i));
            }

        }

        sk_X509_pop_free(ca, X509_free);
        X509_free(cert);
        EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);    
        fclose(fp);

    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        retVal = false;
        std::cout <<"Error parsing/decrypting pkcs12 file into PEM or writing temporary pem file" << e.what() << std::endl;        
    }
```

Here are the includes I used

```
//for ssl connection
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/context_base.hpp>

//for parsing key file
#include <openssl/pkcs12.h>
```