# HTTPS client with cpp-netlib - sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, cpp-netlib

I am trying to set up a simple HTTPS client in C++ to test some features against the [Reqres](https://reqres.in) API.

I am using [cpp-netlib](https://cpp-netlib.org/) as the main C++ network library. Based on the examples provided in the documentation, I wrote some code to perform some GET queries:

```
#ifndef BOOST_NETWORK_ENABLE_HTTPS
#    define BOOST_NETWORK_ENABLE_HTTPS
#endif // !BOOST_NETWORK_ENABLE_HTTPS

#include <boost/network/protocol/http/client.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::network::http;

int main() {
    client::options options;
    options.follow_redirects(true)
        .cache_resolved(true)
        .timeout(10);
    client client_(options);

    client::request request_("https://reqres.in/api/users");
    client::response response_ = client_.get(request_);
    std::cout << body(response_) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When, I run the code, I get this exception:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::system::system_error>: sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I think the problem is related to the OpenSSL configuration. I have tried to generate a certificate to use in the handshake by generating the CSR and KEY:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout mohabouje.key -out mohabouje.csr
```

and then the PEM:

```
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in mohabouje.csr -signkey mohabouje.key -out mohabouje.pem
```

I have modified the code, to use those files in the client options:

```
client::options options;
options.follow_redirects(true)
    .cache_resolved(true)
    .openssl_certificate_file("/opt/ssl/mohabouje.csr")
    .openssl_private_key_file("/opt/ssl/mohabouje.key")
    .timeout(10);
```

But now, I am getting this exception:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error>: use_certificate_file: no start line
```

Alternative, I have tried this:

```
client::options options;
options.follow_redirects(true)
   .cache_resolved(true)
   .openssl_certificate_file("/opt/ssl/mohabouje.pem")
   .openssl_private_key_file("/opt/ssl/mohabouje.key")
   .timeout(10);
```

But, I get the same exception:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::system::system_error>: sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

**What am I doing wrong? Could anyone provide a working example of a simple query against this public API?**

Comment: Clients of reqres do not need client certificates (and definitely not self-signed ones). Seems like your problem here is TLS is not enabled... See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984534/https-client-get-with-cpp-netlib-using-a-client-certificate-and-password

Comment: Looks very much like a Server Name Indication (SNI) problem. I don't know anything about cpp-netlib, but usually you would need to provide the hostname at the handshake, s.t. the server knows which certificate it should go with.